# What is the dimension of keras input for train data for ordinary dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am quite beginner for keras. My dataset is pretty much like any ordinary dataset. It has 25K samples each of 382 features. I thought to treat each sample as a sequence and then feed them to the LSTM. What is the dimension of keras train dataset? I try (25K, 382, 1), is it true?

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train_values, (25K, 382, 1))
```

And also in model fitting i used like this for model input_shape, Is it true?

```
model.add(LSTM(379, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, input_shape=(382, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's more than code to you question so SO may not be the right place for it.

That being said, I wrote a comprehensive tutorial in 2015 on how to deal with sequences in Keras. Some of it may be outdated but the main ideas are still relevant, especially regarding the dimensionality questions you have: https://vict0rs.ch/tutorials/keras/recurrent/

In particular:

> we reshape the inputs to have dimensions (#examples, #values in sequences, dim. of each value). Here each value is 1-dimensional, they are only one measure (of power consumption at time t). However if we were to predict speed vectors they could be 3 dimensional for instance.

and

```
model.add(LSTM(
        input_dim=layers[0],
        output_dim=layers[1],
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```